# How to decrease user code size for a Xamarin Forms App in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 RTM on Windows 7 today and registered a new account on Xamarin (Starter License).

After creating the project:

[image]

I tried to run the application (AVD created before). All what I got was this error:

> mandroid error XA9005: User code size, 2949503 bytes, is larger than
> 131072 and requires aáBusinessá(or higher) License.
>
> mandroid error
> XA9006: Using type `Android.Runtime.JNIEnv`
> requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License.

It's clear what I have to do, but I don't want to change to the business license. Personally, it makes no sense, that I can't run a blank, freshly created project without upgrading my license.

What can I do to reduce the 'user code size'?

Comment: There's also the Indie-license to consider. It's a lot cheaper than Business. Then again, it won't work with JNIEnv :-/

Comment: I know. But VS 2015 RTM comes with the Starter license and I wan't to use this license to try it. But if not even a blank project works, what does? What can I do with the Starter license?

Comment: There is a list of Starter samples at the bottom of this page - http://xamarin.com/starter - to help you try it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, you can't use the "Xamarin.Forms" part of xamarin in the starter edition. That is their cross platform UI library. You should be fine creating a non Xamarin.Forms app.

Comment: Thank's that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

**Xamarin.Forms** works only with Indie / Bussiness editions.