# Error: [feature] requires a Business (or higher) license

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, compiler-errors

i get these 2 error:

Errore      User code size, 168315 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires aáBusinessá(or higher) License.

Errore      Using type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute` requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License.

Comment: [The answer is in the link below][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555886/how-to-decrease-user-code-size-for-a-xamarin-forms-app-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: please try to use meaningful titles in your questions: "Error in Xamarin" is incredibly vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your asking why are you suddenly getting this now when it was working fine before.

When you installed Xamarin you got a free trial license that lasts for 30 or 90 days dependent. Once that expires you revert back to the free license which has no Visual Studio support and is limited to very small IL footprints.

I assume your free trial license has expired and now you gotta cough up cash or live with the limitations.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen without account expiration.  I received the same error on a brand new installation of VS 2015 with a brand new Xamarin account.  I created a new Cross-Platform Blank App (**Xamarin.Forms Portable**).  Made no changes, simple attempted to compile and received the following errors:

> Error     User code size, 2950015 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires aáBusinessá(or higher) License.
>   Error       Using type `Android.Runtime.JNIEnv` requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License.

I also am attempting to explore and learn Xamarin and this represents my initial customer experience.  Being unable to even compile a base template app doesn't encourage me to go purchase any kind of license.

Answer (score 1):

Those are pretty explicit errors: you are using features that require a Xamarin Business license.  Either stop using those features, or upgrade your license.