# Unable to use XAMARIN trial version

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have installed a 30 day trial and lost 1 day to install problems and want to see Xamarin.Forms and with the new project template I get this error  Error 2 User code size, 2950527 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires aáBusinessá(or higher) License. HelloWorldApp.Droid  Error 3 Using type Android.Runtime.JNIEnv requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License. HelloWorldApp.Droid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31561183/4984832

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrease user code size for a Xamarin Forms App in Visual Studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555886/how-to-decrease-user-code-size-for-a-xamarin-forms-app-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: If Xamarin.Forms is NOT supported in Starter edition, how to go ahead with a project-specific ProofOfConcept? Is it possible with the Blank (Shared) templates; require the ListView kind of control atleast. Once POC is approved by our business, would be able to go for Business Edition. Suggest workarounds

Answer (score 1):

This Question is already answered on Stackoverflow, 
[follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?)

answering your question, You can not use Xamarin.Forms on Starter Edition
you can use Xamarin.Android with starter edition.
but make sure you don't exceed 128kb Code file.
you cannot use the external libraries as it gives the error for code size.
yes, you can build hello world application in Xamarin.Android